# Null Dereference C#

Tags: c#, null, dereference

```
if (ddl.SelectedValue != "")
```

After using Fortify to analyze my code, Fortify show me a vulnerability which is "Null Dereference".

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: ... check if it's null or empty....?

Comment: `ddl` might be null

Comment: @Rob: controls are usually instantiated, but yes...

Comment: @MitchWheat Sure - but if fortify behaves like other analyzers, there may be a null check above this code which doesn't skip this code path if `ddl` is null.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `ddl` can never be null:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl.SelectedValue)
{

}
```

Otherwise:

```
if (ddl != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl.SelectedValue)
{

}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why `IsNullOrEmpty` rather than the `!= ""` check? In both cases, `ddl` can never be null ("assuming" for the first, and the explicit check for the second).

Comment: because selectedvalue might be null, and idiomatically that's the common .Net style rather than if(ddl.SelectedValue != null && ddl.SelectedValue != "")

Comment: Ah, I see now, didn't take the `SelectedValue` bit into account. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 6 you have the null dereferencing operator, also called safe navigation operator, so you can do...

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl?.SelectedValue)
{
    // ddl can be null and this will not throw.
}
```